# Kolmogorov Complexity: Is there a Program P which outputs Kolmogorov string K, P doesn't contain K and P is longer than K?

Tags: complexity-theory, kolmogorov-complexity

Given a binary string, K, with length N, and Kolmogorov Complexity N, is there a program P, of length M, and with Kolmogorov Complexity M such that:

1. P outputs K.
2. M >= N.
3. P does not contain K.

Comment: what does it mean for P to contain K? Cant we just have K' be the bit-wise complement of K, and then P is the program that outputs the bitwise complement of K'?

Comment: I think it means the exact bits are part of the program that outputs K.

Comment: okay, so any program that just produces a concatenation of some prefix of K with the rest of K would work? Or, as in my previous comment, a program that produces the complement of the complement of K?